# Root Crontab Not Running Python Script

Tags: linux, debian, cron, python

I'm running Debian 9. I log in as root and do `crontab -e` and add the following lines:

```
0 */2 * * * python /home/Folder1/Script.py
1 */2 * * * python /home/Folder2/Script.py
2 */2 * * * python /home/Folder3/Script.py
3 */2 * * * python /home/Folder4/Script.py
```

The script's don't run. I've also tried adding `root` before python to specify the user running the script. I believe this crontab is located in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` but I'm not sure if that's the 'main' location. No errors or messages relating to the cron running are reported in `/var/log/syslog`. Nothing is reported in my postfix local mail. I've tried permissions 644 and 744 for the Python scripts.

This cron works when running on a user's crontab, but not root. I've tried this on a personal PC (amd64 Debian 9) and on a VPS (VPS Dime amd64 Debian 9).

Comment: Can you give us an the code of one of these scripts? I want to see if there is an issue with environment variables. You may also want to add some logging to the end of the cronjob. My guess is this has some sort of issue with PATH

Comment: What error messages has `cron` sent you? Run the `mail` command (or read the file `/var/mail/root`)

Comment: You could save a lot of disk space by using 0-3 as the first column.  You'll gain time to when you have to correct your crontab.

Comment: There's nothing in the script itself that prevents it from running when called by root?

Answer (score 1):

You should first add the path for Python when using crontab.

Assuming this actually is the correct full location of the script, you need the following:

```
0 */2 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/Folder1/Script.py
```

You also need to verify environmental variables in your script are absolute paths, because keep in mind cronjobs will see these variables differently.

Comment: It's unlikely to be an issue with the interpreter's path, but more likely to be an issue with environment variables used by the script itself.

Comment: @Kusalananda, nonsense, original crontab has no environment, EDubman is right.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille "No environment", really? Try running `env >"$HOME/cron.env"` in a cron job.  Unless the system's default configuration has been totally disfigured, that should output `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` to `$HOME/cron.env` along with other environment variables.

Comment: @Kusalananda  I stand corrected.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried adding the full path of Python